# Looping through a list nested in a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop

I have a python dictionary consisting of JSON results. The dictionary contains a nested dictionary, which contains a nested list which contains a nested dictionary. Still with me? Here's an example:

```
{'hits':{'results':[{'key1':'value1', 
                    'key2':'value2', 
                    'key3':{'sub_key':'sub_value'}},
                   {'key1':'value3',
                    'key2':'value4',
                    'key3':{'sub_key':'sub_value2'}}
                  ]}}
```

What I want to get from the dictionary is the `sub_vale` of each `sub_key` and store it in a different list. No matter what I try I keep getting errors.

This was my last attempt at it:

```
inner_list=mydict['hits']['results']#This is the list of the inner_dicts

index = 0
    for x in inner_list:
        new_dict[index] = x[u'sub_key']
        index = index + 1

print new_dict
```

It printed the first few results then started to return everything in the original dictionary. I can't get my head around it. If I replace the `new_dict[index]` line with a `print` statement it prints to the screen perfectly. Really need some input on this!

```
for x in inner_list:
    print x[u'sub_key']
```

Comment: Please post the erroneous output. The program looks correct, so I have a feeling I don't understand what it's doing that is contrary to what you expect

Comment: @inspectorG4dget just ran that exact code there and got traceback error `File "C:\Python27\test.py", line 24, in main
    newresults[index] = x[u'sub_key']
IndexError: list assignment index out of range`

Comment: If `newresults` is what you've posted as `new_dict` and is a `list`, then try `append`ing to it, as opposed to assigning to an index that doesn't yet exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After making some assumptions:

```
[e['key3']['sub_key'] for e in x['hits']['results']]
```

To change every instance:

```
for e in x['hits']['results']:
 e['key3']['sub_key'] = 1
```

Comment: Thanks that's it. I started out as a C programmer so I find the python syntax strange still. What if I wanted to change the value of the subkey then? As in change sub_value to sub_value_y

Comment: @adohertyd : for instance `x['hits']['results'][0]['key3']['sub_key'] = y`

Comment: What about changing it in every instance though? As in a loop?

Comment: Thank you very much this has made life much easier for me

Answer (score 1):

`x` is a dictionary

on the first iteration of `for x in ...`

```
x={'key1':'value1', 
                'key2':'value2', 
                'key3':{'sub_key':'sub_value'}},
```

notice that there is no key `sub_key` in `x` but rather in `x['key3']['sub_key']`

Comment: Why then, when I do `print x['sub_key']` it prints no problem?

Comment: It doesnt for me ...  it raises an error
`
>>> for x in inner:
...     print x[u'sub_key']
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
KeyError: u'sub_key'`

Comment: remove the u from the front of sub_key sorry

Comment: nope ... still not ... there is oviously something you are doing to inner list  in the middle that you are not including... 

x has no key 'sub_key' .... only x['key3'] has 'sub_key'

Comment: I must have changed something in the code since the print statement worked for me so! But thanks for the input

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> dic={'hits':{'results':[{'key1':'value1', 
                    'key2':'value2', 
                    'key3':{'sub_key':'sub_value'}},
                   {'key1':'value3',
                    'key2':'value4',
                    'key3':{'sub_key':'sub_value2'}}
                  ]}}
>>> inner_list=dic['hits']['results']
>>> [x[y]['sub_key'] for x in inner_list for y in x if isinstance(x[y],dict)]
['sub_value', 'sub_value2']
```

and if you're sure that it's `key3` that always contain the inner `dict`, then :

```
>>> [x['key3']['sub_key'] for x in inner_list]
['sub_value', 'sub_value2']
```

without using `List comprehensions`:

```
>>> lis=[]
>>> for x in inner_list:
    for y in x:
        if isinstance(x[y],dict):
            lis.append(x[y]['sub_key'])


>>> lis
['sub_value', 'sub_value2']
```

Comment: Wow that's a mouthful there! I'm not making this easy on myself at all!

Comment: Thanks so much! As I said to Marco, I'm still in the C programming mode so the python syntax is still a bit strange to me. Thank you.

Comment: yes, List Comprehensions are slighly hard to understand for a new python programmer, so I added a simple version of the answer(w/o using List comprehension)

Answer (score 1):

The index error is coming from `new_dict[index]` where `index` is larger than the size of `new_dict`.

List comprehension should be considered. It is generally better, but to help understand how this works in a loop. Try this instead.

```
new_list = []
for x in inner_list:
    new_list.append(x[u'sub_key'])

print new_list
```

If you want to stick with a dict, but use index for a key try this:

```
index = 0
new_dict = {}
    for x in inner_list:
        new_dict[index] = x[u'sub_key']
        index = index + 1

print new_dict
```

Ok, based on your comments below, I think this is what you wanted.

```
inner_list=mydict['hits']['results']#This is the list of the inner_dicts

new_dict = {}
for x in inner_list:
    new_dict[x['key2']] = x['key3']['sub_key']

print new_dict
```

Comment: Yes it's part of a larger program where I am taking specific elements from 3 dictionaries, putting them in lists and comparing them based on certain criteria. It's easier to do that from a list I think

Comment: Chip what if I wanted to create a dictionary from some of the elements of the original dictionary. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Really similar to the syntax in your code actually, but you need a string for a key. new_dict[key] = value. What element did you want to use for the key and which one for the value.

Comment: We'll say I want to create a new dictionary with `key2` and `sub_key` and leaving out the rest

Comment: is key2 a static value or does that change? If you are wanting the second element in a dict that is not going to work because dicts are unordered...

Comment: The keys are always the same, both their names and their positions in the dictionary. When the main dictionary is returned, I need to get each instance of key2 and subkey and put them in a new dictionary. I hope that makes sense!

Comment: That't not exactly it but I see what you're getting at. What I want is `new_dict`={'key2':'key2_value_from_main_dict','sub_key':'sub_value_from_main_dict'} this should store each `key2` and `subkey` along with their corresponding values from the main dict

Answer (score 1):

You forgot on level of nesting.

```
for x in inner_list:
    for y in x:
        if isinstance(x[y], dict) and 'sub_key' in x[y]:
            new_dict.append( x[y]['sub_key'] )
```